# Search Listview In Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, search

I have searched the web on how to add search functionality to my Flutter application. I have a list view that gets data from a mysql database and pass it as a json string. I want to add a search box on top of the list, when the user enters a string, it will take the string and search the name field of the list and re-populate the list. Here is my code please.

Thank you.

```
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    HomeState createState() => HomeState();
    }

    class HomeState extends State<Home> {
    Future<List<Attendants>> students;
    final studentListKey = GlobalKey<HomeState>();
    
    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    students = getStudentList();
    }

    Future<List<Attendants>> getStudentList() async {
    final response = await http.get("${Env.URL_PREFIX}/list.php");

    final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    List<Attendants> students = items.map<Attendants>((json) {
      return Attendants.fromJson(json);
    }).toList();

    return students;
    }

    void refreshStudentList() {
    setState(() {
      students = getStudentList();
     });
     }
  

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       key: studentListKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Members List'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,),
              onPressed: null),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              refreshStudentList();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Attendants>>(
          future: students,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

            // Render student lists
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var data = snapshot.data[index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.view_list),
                    title: Text(
                      data.name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        EnterExitRoute(
                          exitPage: Home(),
                          enterPage: Details(attendants: data),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return Create();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
    }
    }
```

Let me know if my question is not clear so I can explain it further

Answer (score 0):

If you get all objects about your search in the future function
add your code :

```
 // By default, show a loading spinner.
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          var list = snapshot.data.where((student){
       // Or some other query..
      return student[“some”].contains(searchTerm);
}).toList();

 return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            var data = list[index];
    ..............
```

Else if not, this is a different subject in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`searchable_listview`](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_listview) package:

1. **Add the package to your project**:

```yaml
dependencies:
 searchable_listview: ^2.9.0
```

2. **Import the package**: In your Dart file, import the `searchable_listview` package:

```dart
import 'package:searchable_listview/searchable_listview.dart';
```

3. **Use `SearchableList` in your UI**: In your UI, you can use the `SearchableList` widget to display the list and handle the search. You need to provide a `builder` function that returns a widget for each item in the list. The `filter` function is used to filter the list based on the search query. Here's an example:

```dart
SearchableList<Attendants>(
 initialList: snapshot.data,
 builder: (Attendants attendant) => ListTile(
   leading: Icon(Icons.person),
   trailing: Icon(Icons.view_list),
   title: Text(
     attendant.name,
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
   ),
   onTap: () {
     Navigator.push(
       context,
       EnterExitRoute(
         exitPage: Home(),
         enterPage: Details(attendants: attendant),
       ),
     );
   },
 ),
 filter: (value) => snapshot.data.where((attendant) => attendant.name.contains(value)).toList(),
)
```

In this example, `initialList` is the initial list of attendants. The `builder` function returns a `ListTile` for each attendant. The `filter` function filters the list based on the search query [Source 2](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_listview).

4. **Replace the `ListView.builder` with `SearchableList`**: In your `build` method, replace the `ListView.builder` with the `SearchableList` widget:

```dart
return SearchableList<Attendants>(
 initialList: snapshot.data,
 builder: (Attendants attendant) => ListTile(
   leading: Icon(Icons.person),
   trailing: Icon(Icons.view_list),
   title: Text(
     attendant.name,
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
   ),
   onTap: () {
     Navigator.push(
       context,
       EnterExitRoute(
         exitPage: Home(),
         enterPage: Details(attendants: attendant),
       ),
     );
   },
 ),
 filter: (value) => snapshot.data.where((attendant) => attendant.name.contains(value)).toList(),
);
```

This should add search functionality to your ListView in Flutter. The list will be updated in real-time as the user types into the search field.